Search for currency pairs
I am trying to learn more about Python.  I am trying to pull some data from Yahoo Finance.  I have this code:
import yfinance as yf
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen

symbols = ['AMZN', 'AAPL']
start = '2020-01-01'
end = '2024-01-16'
data = yf.download(symbols, start=start, end=end)['Adj Close']
specified_number = 0 
coint_test_result = coint_johansen(data, specified_number, 1)
print("End")

It works as expected.  I then change the symbols (line four to crypto currency pairs i.e.
symbols = ['BTCUSD', 'ETHUSD']

The code then errors on this line:
coint_test_result = coint_johansen(data, specified_number, 1)

The error is: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
Why does it error with cryptocurrency pairs as symbols?
I have version 3.12.3 of Python.

Are you confident that the symbols shouldn’t be “BTC-USD” and “ETH-USD”?

You haven't said what versions of Python or yfinance you're using. With Python 3.12.4 and yfinance 0.2.40, you will see "failed download" errors when the symbols are BTCUSD and ETHUSD
